# Why are some ATP CTP providers not on the FAA's approved list?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, airline-pilot

The FAA has published a list of [ATP CTP provider schools](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/training/atp/media/ATP_CTP_Providers.pdf). But I can still find other schools not listed in this list, like ["ATP flight school"](https://atpflightschool.com/atp/ctp/).

I'm sure that only approved facilities can provide an ATP CTP course. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAA's ATP-CTP Advisory Circular 61-138](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-138_CHG_1.pdf) does not prohibit a qualified ATP-CTP instructor using an approved training program from delivering the training at any facility that is willing to pay for their services.